# ArithGeo(arr) CoderByte Ruby: Why doesn't this solution work for certain test case scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Below I have posted the instructions for this problem along with my solution. A few test case scenarios have failed, but seem to be working for most. Can anybody help out at which point I've gone wrong? Any help is much appreciated!!

- Using the Ruby language, have the function ArithGeo(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string "Arithmetic" if the sequence follows an arithmetic pattern or return "Geometric" if it follows a geometric pattern.
- If the sequence doesn't follow either pattern return -1.
- An arithmetic sequence is one where the difference between each of the numbers is consistent
- Arithmetic example: [2, 4, 6, 8]
- In a geometric sequence, each term after the first is multiplied by some constant or common ratio.
- Geometric example: [2, 6, 18, 54]
- Negative numbers may be entered as parameters, 0 will not be entered, and no array will contain all the same elements.

Code:

```
def arithGeo(num)

  idx = 0
  while idx < num.length

    if ((num[idx] - num[idx + 1]) == (num[idx + 1] - num[idx + 2]))
      return "Arithmetic"
    elsif ((num[idx + 1] / num[idx]) == (num[idx + 2] / num[idx + 1]))
      return "Geometric"
    else
      return "-1"
    end

  idx += 1
  end

end

 #Test Cases that Failed

 p arithGeo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20])

 p arithGeo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 88, 2])

 p arithGeo([10, 110, 210, 310, 410, 511])
```

Comment: You need to clarify some things: What was returned for the failed test cases? Did they return -1 and is that what you expected since they don't follow either of the rules you have set up?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this a homework problem or a problem for a tutorial? If so, strongly consider whether you want people to tell you how to solve the problem, or do you want to learn on your own? In real, professional, life we don't get a lot of opportunity to ask others how to do our work. Do it regularly and you'll need to find another job. Instead we dig in and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, lets do a much more "ruby like" way:

```
def arith?(arr)
  check_arr = []
  arr.reverse.inject {|memo, num| check_arr << (memo - num); num}
    #loop through from highest to lowest, subtracting each from the next and store in check_arr
  check_arr.all? {|num| num == check_arr[-1]}
    #check that all results are the same in the arr i.e. [2,2,2,2,2]
end
```

This returns `true` if all of the operations return the same result, thus a linear progression.

```
def geo?(arr)
  check_arr = []
  arr.reverse.inject {|memo, num| check_arr << (memo / num); num}
    #loop through from highest to lowest, dividing each by the next and store in check_arr
  check_arr.all? {|x| x == check_arr[-1]}
    #check that all products are the same in the arr i.e. [3,3,3,3,3]
end
```

This returns true if all of the operations return the same result, thus a geometric progression.

Now use those methods in your other method

```
def arith_geo?(arr)

  if arith?(arr)
    'Arithmetic' 
  elsif geo?(arr)
     'Geometric'
  else
    -1
  end

end
```

Comment: After thetinman's comment, it does look like this might be a homework assignment. I'll leave my answer, but realize that if it is school work and you just copy the answer then your teacher may expect you to be able to explain what is going on with `inject()` and how it works. Looking at your code it looked as if you were coming to ruby from another language. Things like the capitalized method name and your while statement are not very ruby-like.

Comment: I assure you this is not a homework assignment. I have been looking up a number of problems from resources, such as this one from CoderByte, trying to teach myself Ruby. I am new to programming (been practicing on my own for a couple months) and am starting to understand how to create methods.

Comment: Does this answer make sense to you. I can explain any thing you need clarified. If you are new to Ruby you should go to ruby-doc.org and read the docs on Enumerable. Inject can be tough to grasp at first but is incredibly handy in cases like this. I've tested this solution and can't find a case where it fails.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your feedback. The answer does make sense and I agree, inject is a bit confusing but after manipulating a few cases, I feel I understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You did use a `while` but you do not loop over the data, because you write `return` you will only ever look at the first three numbers and then *immediately* return the result. You will have to keep the previous result, and make sure the result stays the same to return either geometric or arithmetic.

This should help you to complete the exercise :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This really helped and I found a number of issues in this code, including the fact that I was creating a nil value while looping through the full length of the array and coming to the end result + 1/+ 2. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the solution in JavaScript and this is what I came up with:

```
function algoGeo(arr){
    var algo = true;
    var geo = true;
    //first check algo
    for(var k = 1; k < arr.length; k++){
        if( (arr[0] + (arr[1] - arr[0]) * k) !== arr[k] && algo ){
            algo = false;
        }
        if( arr[0] * Math.pow(arr[1] / arr[0], k) !== arr[k] && geo){
            geo = false;
        }
    }
    return algo ? "Arithmetic" : geo ? "Geometric" : -1; 
}

var arr = [5,12,19,26];
console.log(algoGeo(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ArithGeo(arr)
  diff1 = []
  diff2 = []
  arr.each_index do |x|
    if(x + 1 < arr.length)
      diff1 << arr[x + 1] - arr[x]
      diff2 << arr[x + 1] / arr[x]
     end
    end
  diff1.uniq.size == 1 ? "Arithmetic" : diff2.uniq.size == 1 ? "Geometric" : -1
end
```

A little late but this is what i came up with when trying to solve this same question.